# twisted critical unhandled error no tutorial de scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Sou novo em programação e estou tentando realizar o tutorial de scrapy http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Uso python 2.7 e windows 7. Quando rodo no cmd o comando "scrapy crawl dmoz" recebo como mensagem as seguintes informações:

```
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':     'tu
torial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME':   'tutorial'}

2015-07-14 16:11:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsol
e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-07-14 16:11:06 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-07-14 16:11:07 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Meu arquivo spider está em tutorial/tutorial/spider.
Saberiam me dizer como descubro qual erro é, ou como resolvo esse problema?

Grato pela atenção

Comment: Olá, Vinícius! Pode colar o código completo do spider? Se puder mandar o projeto inteiro num zip, melhor ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser devido ao módulo pywin32 que apenas tenha sido carregado mas não instalado. Tenta instalá-lo desta forma:

```
python python27\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

Um problema semelhante pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439540/twisted-critical-unhandled-error-on-scrapy-tutorial).